# SendTo / Open With

Tags: java, swing, install4j

How can I add my application to SendTo or Open With using Install4J?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Class ´WinAssociation´, there is a method

```
static void create( java.lang.String extension, 
                    java.lang.String description, 
                    java.io.File iconFile, 
                    java.io.File executable)
// Creates a file association.
```

This should create a file-extension, which is opened with zur provided application.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to have my app shortcut in Send To menu, does it have such a method too? Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you already got your answer on how to create an association, so here's the other answer.

The Send-To menu is actually just a directory in your user profile, called `SendTo`, so all you need to do it place a shortcut there.  See: [How to Add Items to the "Send To" Menu in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310270).  As long as Install4J can place files wherever you ask, and you know how to create shortcuts, this should be trivial.